# How can I link battery life to resistivity of a phone PCB?

Tags: pcb, cellphone, mobile

Are there any equations/relevant explanations that can link resistivity of the "wiring"* (or other components) on a phone's PCB to its battery life, i.e. can I prove that using silver wires would extend battery life compared to copper wires, and by how much?

**I know its not actual wires, but I have no idea what the metal line things are called.*

Comment: Most people call them traces, and no, they will not have any measurable effect. Silver has only a few percent better resistivity than copper, and the majority of losses on a phone is definetly not in the traces.

Comment: The PCB has negligible effect on the battery life. Even if it was superconducting the battery life would not be measurably affected.

Comment: ... but in any case, decreasing the resistance will generally (with a few exceptions) *increase* current flow, which will *decrease* battery life.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I don't know if you are just trying to make a joke, but it is certainly not true in any meaningful way that adding resistance to PCB traces will help battery life. Parasitic resistances generally reduce battery life.

Comment: @mkeith: No, I'm not joking. Forget about the traces -- just take any circuit and increase the resistances by, say, 10%. Does the battery life go up or down?

Comment: @DaveTweed If your circuit involves anything like a DC-DC converter then increasing resistance will increase power consumption, leading to a decrease in battery life.

Comment: @brhans: Yes, the input side of a DC-DC converter is a constant-power load, and that's one of the exceptions that I was alluding to. But that has no bearing on what's happening on the *output* side of the converter.

Comment: @DaveTweed, the OP is asking about a mobile phone. I think it is safe to assume that it has a DC-DC converter. It is also fairly common for lithium powered devices to have a 3.3V or 3V rail. The end of a discharge cycle may be dictated by when the LDO can no longer keep the 3 or 3.3V rail up. Depressing VBATT by adding series resistance will hasten that event. I design battery powered hand held consumer goods for a living. I have never found that adding resistance to a product improved battery life...

Comment: Of course, if your test circuit is so trivial that it only consists of a battery with a resistor as a load, then, yes, increasing resistance will make the battery last longer. But that is totally unrealistic. I suggest you measure the battery life of your cell phone with and without a series resistor in place and report back to the group with your findings.

Comment: @mkeith: Most of the PCB traces in a cell phone (or any other device, for that matter) are on the load side of the DC-DC converter. We can generally assume that that bus is held at a constant voltage by the converter. The OP is asking about the resistance of traces in general, not just the connections to the battery.

Comment: System designer would have to increase the DC-DC setpoint to maintain correct functionality. So even the traces on the regulated side of the DC-DC will cause losses that have to be compensated for.

Comment: Thanks for the info... so, using for example a more energy efficient screen will increase battery life because it has a lower resistance (and therefore smaller net resistivity of screen itself)?

Comment: @Lukeme9X, you can improve battery life at the system design stage by using a more efficient screen. Or, you could keep battery life the same, but make the screen brighter. But you also have to consider whether the more efficient screen costs more, and whether it might be cheaper to simply add a larger battery. Of course, if the mechanical envelope does not allow for a larger battery, then you don't have that option. Always there are tradeoffs in design.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the comments, the answer is conditional.

In most cases, in a modern piece of electronics, using a more conductive element in place of copper will reduce power losses across that trace. It is worth pointing out, though, that with the miniscule currents used in a typical mobile device, there shouldn't be any meaningful gain in battery life, especially not when compared to cost.

Heating power losses are linearly related to resistance, but are geometrically related to current flow. Silver only has about 5 percent better conductivity than copper, so, for the same amperage, could reduce those heating power losses by about 5 percent.

Keep in mind, though, that a mobile phone doesn't employ a fan - it has to dissipate all heat generated through it's case. So some very clever people already had to reduce those heating power losses to get it to work at all. They really are quite small in comparison to the amount of power consumed by the active electronics, especially a big, pretty touchscreen or a radio that passes high-speed data to a tower miles away - that's where all the power is going. A five percent reduction in heating power just from the pcb wouldn't be noticed.